# How to get ID of every role and member mentioned

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

So I'm making a discord bot using discord.js v13, and there is a command where I would like the user to be able to mention multiple members in 1 message or use their ID. But I'm having some trouble with this. I've tried:

```
   let UserID = message.mentions
   console.log(UserID)
```

But this didn't log only the **user IDs**, it also console logged some other information. If you know how to get **only the user IDs** please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get users you mentioned IDs, you need to use [`message.mentions.users.map`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.3/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) and get such code as result:

```js
let userIDs = message.mentions.users.map(m => m.id).join("\n")
console.log(userIDs)
```

P.S. If you also need users' nicknames use `.map(m => m.username + " " + m.id)`

Comment: Hey again, I would like to ask if you know of a way to do the same except with roles instead of users? If you do please let me know.
Thanks again.

Comment: Yea, you basically change `users` to `roles` and that's it

Comment: MrMythical, I just said if they need to get user nickname **and** their ID, they can use this line of code